# Uniqueness of smooth structure on a set

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

The question states that if $M$ is a manifold and $B$ be a set and $F:M \to B$ is a bijection then to show there exists a unique smooth structure on $B$ that $F$ is a diffeomorphism.

I am really not sure how to get a smooth structure on $B$ using the bijective ness of the given function $F$ also how to get the uniqueness. Any hints regarding how to proceed would be very much helpful.

Comment: Hint: if $\varphi$ is a chart for $M$, consider $\tilde{\varphi} =  \varphi\circ F^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to transfer on $B$ the topology structure:

$\tau_B:=\{ V: F^{-1}(U) \in \tau\}$

is a topology on $B$, where $\tau$ is the topology on $M$. This is the quotient topology of the map $F$ on $B$ and it’s the biggest topology such that the map is continuos. In our case $F$ becomes an homeomorphism.

This permit us to say that $B$ is Hausdorff and second countable.

Now you have to define an atlas on $B$:

$\mathcal{A}_B:=\{(F(U), \phi_U\circ F^{-1})\}_{\{(U,\phi_U)\in \mathcal{A}\}}$

With respect this atlas $B$ is a manifold and $F$ becomes a diffeomorphism.

General fact:
Given a manifold $N$ with two differentiable structures $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{A}’$, then they are equivalent if and only if there exists a diffeomorphism

$G: (N, \mathcal{A}) \to (N, \mathcal{A}’)$

This permit us to say that $\mathcal{A}_B$ is the only structure on $B$ such that $F$ is a diffeomorphism. In fact if it’s not so, then you can consider

$F\colon (M, \mathcal{A})\to (B, \mathcal{A}_B’)$

And

$F^{-1}\colon (B, \mathcal{A}_B)\to (M,\mathcal{A})$

To have the identity diffeomorphism $F\circ F^{-1}$ and conclude that $\mathcal{A}_B’$ and $\mathcal{A}_B$ are equivalent structures.

Comment: Thanks yes got it. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @User11111: Note that you can *accept* an answer if it solved your problem. Accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/196432) for more information.